# Do I need to buy a NVIDIA graphic card to run deep learning algorithm?

Tags: deep-learning

I am new in deep learning. I am running a MacBook Pro yosemite (upgraded from Snowleopard). I don't have a CUDA-enabled card GPU, and running the code on the CPU is extremely slow. I heard that I can buy some instances on AWS, but it seems that they don't support macOS.

My question is, to continue with the deep learning, do I need to purchase a graphic card? Or is there other solution? I don't want to spend too much on this...

Comment: Can you add some additional information to help clarify your question?  Is the algorithm you are running written by you in CUDA or are you using a package written by someone else?  Does that package or code only run on OSX or are you wondering about connectivity between AWS and OSX?  You can certainly connect a Mac to AWS and run your code/package on AWS in a Linux or Windows environment.  Further, OSX is built on a Unix environment, so most small code packages that run in OSX will run in Linux.

Comment: Thank you AN6U5! I want to use lasagne to train my neural network. And yes, I wrote that code, and will try convolutional NN later. I want to use the AWS instances to accelerate the computation. My doubt came from the AWS website saying that new users have 750h / month of Linux /Windows micro instances usage for free, Mac OS is not included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend familiarizing yourself with [AWS spot instances](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Py0VInjRSBE). It's the most practical solution I can think of for your problem, and [it works your computer too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdR03RpCpac). So, no you don't have to *buy* an Nvidia card, but as of today you will want to use one since almost all the solutions rely on them.

Comment: Hi Emre, thank you for your reply! Actually I am thinking about buying a new laptop since my Macpro is really old. I likeMac, but it seems they don't come with any NVIDIA card. Could you recommand me some laptops suitable for machine learning tasks? (Sorry I know almost nothing about hardware)

Comment: The [Macbook Pro comes with a GeForce GT 750M](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/performance-retina/) with [384 cores](http://www.gpuzoo.com/GPU-NVIDIA/GeForce_GT_750M.html). Outside of Apple, you will probably want a gaming laptop, [such as this Alienware with an Nvidia GTX 980](http://www.laptopmag.com/gaming-laptops), [which has 1536 cores](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-980m/specifications). [Here are some others](http://www.ultrabookreview.com/5729-gaming-laptops-nvidia-970m-980m/). Note that machine learning algorithms outside of deep learning don't need GPUs.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much for the answer, it's more clear for me now!

Comment: I agree with @Emre that machine learning algorithm outside of deep learning don't need GPUs because deep learning /artificial neural networks, can take advantages of a high number of cores for parallel computing (e.g for matrix multipication, if you use deep neural net model)

Answer (score 2):

[AWS GPU instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using_cluster_computing.html) are an option, if you want to do CUDA development. If you don't want to leverage the cloud, you can look into the [Nvidia Jetson TK1](https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-tk1) development kits.  They are about 200 dollars (in July 2015), have 192 CUDA cores, a quad-core ARM processor, and 2GB of RAM.

Conversely, the same amount of money could buy you a 640 CUDA core GeForce GTX 750 Ti, or maybe a 1024 CUDA core GTX 960.  A GT 720 with 1GB RAM and 192 cores could be had for 45 dollars (in July 2015).

You don't *have* to use NVidia GPUs with deep learning.  GPUs will increase the speed dramatically, though.   There is very little support for non-NVidia GPUs with common deep learning toolkits.

Answer (score -1):

AWS does "support" Mac OS. You can use any SSH client from your Mac to access the GPU instance.